# Can't generics return a json object?

Tags: typescript, generics

```
function func<T>(val:string):T{
   return {no1:1,no2:2};
}
```

When I run this code, it says that it cannot return json.

My guess is that if you set a generic as a return type, it can return a value of any type. Why is there no return in this case?

Comment: `T` is not constrained. If you used `T extends { no1: number; no2: number }`, you would find that it works.

Comment: I know that it works if I use the code you gave me. However, I do know that generics are a useful tool when the return type is not clear.
Can't the given code be used under the premise that the return type is clear?

Comment: If the return type is clear, why do you need a generic constraint at all? What's the objective here?

Comment: That's an example, and if the resultJson, which is the response value to the API, is sometimes no1, no2, or no1, no2, no3.., doesn't an error occur even when using return resultJson?

Comment: Types are a compile-time construct. The type system doesn't check your runtime values. If you just want to say "whatever I'm returning here, consider it to be `T`", then you have to `return {no1:1,no2:2} as unknown as T;`